# Git svn clone with author name like "/CN=myname"

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to switch from svn to git on windows 7 using `git svn clone` command.

On one of my repository I try this:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata -A users.txt --username=/CN=john https://path/to/my/repo ./
```

Here is my **users.txt** file:

```
/CN=john = John Doe <john.doe@myself.com>
```

When I git svn clone nothing was displayed just like if everything was ok but no file were cloned. So in **C:/Users/John/.suversion/servers** I've set `neon-debug-mask = 256` to display log errors.

My error is now displayed: `Author: /CN=john not defined in users.txt file` so I think since there is an equal in my username the git clone command can't properly parse the datas.

I've tried escaping `/CN\=john` and quoting `'/CN=john'` `"/CN=john"` but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have an idea for the good way to handle this?

Thank you

Comment: I've found a way not to use users.txt and manage to clone it anyway using `git svn clone -s https://path/to/my/repo ./`. However, if I do a `git log` Author are like `Author: C:/Program Files/Git/CN=john <C:/Program Files/Git/CN=john@2759c1d`

Comment: Had a similar issue for an author with a `hypenated-name`. In my case it erred as a result of a parsing issue because I was trying to omit emails. So I just faked the email addresses and voilà.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution by not using users.txt.

First I do a `git svn clone -s https://path/to/my/repo ./` which clone every files from the repository.

Now if I do a `git log` I've got ugly name and mails for every users and I want to clean that. I've simply used [this gist](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info) which does a `git filter-branch --env-filter` and search & replace authors and mails by the one you provide in the gist.

Beware of this solution because it has to crawl each commit in your repository and you have to launch the script for each branch of your repository.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Upvoted because sometimes you just have to make schtuff work, you know?

Answer (score 2):

`git-svn` cannot currently handle SVN users which have an equals sign "=" in their usernames.

[Here is](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe191fcaa58cb/git-svn.perl#L1836) the relevant code from inside `git-svn`:

```
# '<svn username> = real-name <email address>' mapping based on git-svnimport:
sub load_authors {
            open my $authors, '<', $_authors or die "Can't open $_authors $!\n";
            my $log = $cmd eq 'log';
            while (<$authors>) {
                            chomp;
                            next unless /^(.+?|\(no author\))\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*<(.+)>\s*$/;
                            my ($user, $name, $email) = ($1, $2, $3);
                            if ($log) {
                                            $Git::SVN::Log::rusers{"$name <$email>"} = $user;
                            } else {
                                            $users{$user} = [$name, $email];
                            }
            }
            close $authors or croak $!;
}
```

... as you can see, the regex used to extract usernames from the file will consider only text up to the first "=" as part of the SVN username. Everything after that is considered part of the git username.

This is a bug in `git-svn`.

Possible workarounds off the top of my head:

- I think the first `.+?` in that regex should be greedy, and the last `.+` non-greedy, i.e. `next unless /^(.+|\(no author\))\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*<(.+?)>\s*$/;`

  - You could submit a fix patch to the git project?
  - You could patch your local git scripts for now, and include that in your project’s setup instructions
- You could alias the `git svn` command to include `--authors-prog` option each time, in your `.bash_profile`?
- Can you get a perl script to be run before each git-svn command? If so, you could write perl code which sets `$Git::SVN::Log::rusers` or `$users{$user}` directly?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The best workaround I found was to use the `--authors-prog` option to specify a script converts the svn username eg.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$svnAuthor = $ARGV[0];
if ($svnAuthor =~ /^.*?emailAddress=(.*?)\/CN=(.*?)\/.*$/) {
    print "$2 <$1>";
} else {
     print $svnAuthor;
```

}

This can be set using

```
git config svn.authors-prog <authorScript>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to (temporarily) patch git-svn's load_authors subroutine so the regex pattern had `\s=\s` instead of `\s*=\s*`. Then, I just made sure that all the lines in my authors file had exactly one space surrounding my equals sign on each side. This worked for me, because none of the equals signs in the old usernames had spaces on both sides.